# CSS Vertical Background overlay and a Horizontal Scrollbar appears

Tags: css, overflow, overlay, css-position, horizontal-scrolling

Not sure how to best ask my question. And I can't yet post screenshots. :( This issue does happen in mere current coding practices. You can currently even see this issue happening on Facebooks home page.

Here's my URL:
www.alpacanation.com

**How to replicate live**

Grab the right hand side of your browser and pull inwards. Eventually a scroll bar appears. Not necessarily bad. As I have a fixed with here. However… Notice the scrollbar is the length of the background color up in the top of my header which is actually creating a "Curtain" like effect.

Make matters worse:
If on other high level parent elements like .Footer or .Page you play around with overflow and position relative the curtain will then begin overlaying on top of the entire site.

Check out Facebook: They often have this issue as well. Obviously most don't notice it as it's not going over top of the content.

In either case I know there is something not right. 
Help appreciated!

Comment: This does not reproduce in Chrome, so a screenshot would be beneficial to both of us. :)

Comment: Ways to ask better: (1) figure out the pixel with where you have problems, (2) try to determine the minimum amount of code needed to replicate your problem and add that to your question, (3) http://jsFiddle.net or http://Codepen.io are great resources for creating demos of your problem, instead of sending us to your entire site.

Comment: Protip: Firefox has a [responsive design view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) where you can quickly test out various screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to your CSS:

```
body { min-width: 980px; }
```

You have `min-width: 980px;` set in many of the elements on your page, but not on `html`, `body`, or `.container`. Once the viewport is smaller than this, these elements will overflow `html` and give you the scrollbars you're seeing.

But this doesn't make `html` any bigger. It--and its background--is still at the viewport size. This is why you get the "curtain" effect when you scroll.

Setting `width: 100%` on `html` doesn't fix this; this only sets `html` to 100% width of the browser window. If you're going to use `min-width`, make sure you you don't just apply it to elements that hold your content, but also those that have your backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks so much for that input. It worked!! Super helpful. I never quite understood that but I totally get it now. :)

Comment: @RUBYHAUS, understanding is why I answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

to fix this, add

```
html, body {
    min-width: 980px
}
```

in your www.alpacanation.com/styles.css:40, then you are done. :)

EXPLANATION: the problem is this container,

```
<!— stat container —>
<div class=“container”>
    <!— START FOOTER MENU SECTION —>
```

that container has width:980px which screws up the view because it forces that container to stay at 980px wide while the rest is shrinking, thus creates the ‘curtain’ like effect.

Comment: Thanks so much for that input. It worked!! Super helpful. I never quite understood that but I totally get it now. :)